# Unity3D - transform.position doesn't work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I made this script attached to the shotgun on scene so it would move it in the hierarchy to be a child of player and reset to position to 0,0,0 but the position is random every time. If I run the script to reset position without changing the parent the position will change to 0,0,0:

```
public void Update()
{
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            transform.SetParent(weaponPosition);
            transform.position = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        }
}
```

[On start before pressing E](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycnOE.jpg)

[after pressing E](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHKP6.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You note that even the Inspector tells you: What you see in the Inspector is always the **local** [`Transform.localPosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localPosition.html) relative to the local space of the parent, not the **global** / absolute world space [`Transform.position`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-position.html)!

Only in the case that there is no parent the `position` and `localPosition` are the same.

=> you want to rather use

```
transform.SetParent(weaponPosition);
transform.loalPosition = Vector3.zero;
```

in order to place the object to the pivot of the parent (or world if there is none).